# How do I make Input text box same height in PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

This is what I have:

```
layout = [[sg.VPush(background_color='#3B3B3B')],
    [sg.Text("Type ICAO Code:", text_color='#DCDCDC', background_color='#3B3B3B')],
    [sg.Input("", size=(6), key = '-ICAO CODE-', background_color='#656565', text_color='white', border_width='0'), 
     sg.Button("Search", bind_return_key=True, button_color=('#DCDCDC', '#656565'), border_width='0')],
    [sg.Text("", key = '-RESULT-', text_color='#DCDCDC', background_color='#3B3B3B')],
[sg.VPush(background_color='#3B3B3B')]]
```

This is what it looks like now:

[image]

How do I make the input box the same height as the button?

Tried doing `size(6,2)`, but the input box only gets wider and not taller.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 40, 'bold'))
layout = [[sg.Input(size=10), sg.Button("Search")]]
sg.Window("Title", layout).read(close=True)
```

[image]

> size
>
> (w, h) where w is for characters-wide, and h for rows-high. If an int is supplied rather than a tuple, then a tuple is created width=int supplied and heigh=1

Actually, the height for rows-high is always set to 1.

To fit the width and height, you can try to use the options `expand_x` and `expand_y`.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 40, 'bold'))
layout = [[sg.Input(size=10, expand_y=True), sg.Button("Search")]]
sg.Window("Title", layout).read(close=True)
```

[image]